# Trim Molding Help

Tags: trim

I have a contractor who is installing 5/8" thick carbonized bamboo flooring upstairs. Poor planning on his part created large gaps between the base boards and the last run of flooring about an inch and a half to 3/4ths of width.  On top of this he left two coworkers on the job who know nothing of trim work. I sent them home. so how does one fix this problem without tearing up existing work. On one part of a bedroom he bumped out the space on the floor with a piece of molding the same height as the 3/4" molding to get a fit.  Help!  I am about to fire the whole crew.

Comment: -1 for the ranting. Please edit this to focus on your question. As written, the answer is to lower your trim, replace the trim with a wider piece, or go over the trim with another piece. But you didn't provide enough detail or a photo to determine which would be the best option. See [what topics can I ask about here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: Picture would help... Sounds like you need another piece of flooring added not trim.

Comment: A picture would definitely help. Sounds like a poor installation. No real fix other than building up a thick baseboard. (FWIW, I remove baseboard before installing new flooring)

Answer (score 1):

Make them rip some floor boards down to the appropriate width and install them to narrow the gap.

It would be virtually impossible to make it work out exactly where you only have full-width floor boards. Has this guy never installed wood flooring before?